# How to use distm() to get the distance between each coordinate in the first data frame to all coordinates in another data frame and record them?

Tags: r, geospatial

first data frame has 5 coordinates and the second data frame has another 5 coordinates.

from:

```
data frame 1 <- data.frame(longitude = c(-1.482156, -1.482318, -1.482129, -1.484275, -1.485866), 
                           latitude= c(54.90083, 54.90078, 54.90077, 54.90011, 54.89936),
                           ID = c(A,B,C,D,E))

data frame 2 <- data.frame (longitude  =c( -1.482880, -1.485735, -1.485770, -1.485913),
                            latitude = c( 54.89935, 54.89935, 54.89879, 54.89902),
                            ID = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

to:

Outcome to provide a matrix of distances between the two data frames.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply remove the last column 'ID' and apply `distm`

```
library(geosphere)
distm(df2[-3], df1[-3])
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 171.1779 163.2218 165.2558 123.1550 191.56772
#[2,] 282.5995 270.9150 280.1868 126.2177   8.47761
#[3,] 324.5419 313.2399 321.1614 175.4751  63.75154
#[4,] 314.1523 302.6183 311.2599 160.5186  37.96928
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(longitude = c(-1.482156, -1.482318, -1.482129, 
-1.484275, -1.485866), latitude = c(54.90083, 54.90078, 54.90077, 
54.90011, 54.89936), ID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(longitude = c(-1.48288, -1.485735, -1.48577, -1.485913
), latitude = c(54.89935, 54.89935, 54.89879, 54.89902), ID = c(1, 
2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```